# nanoseconds difference for java.time.Instant testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, instant

I have tests where I compare `java.time.Instant` dates. When I run these tests locally, everything works correctly. But remote build fails due to tests.

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <2023-07-14T23:54:08.606213692Z> but was: <2023-07-14T23:54:08.606214Z>
```

The difference is literally in nanoseconds. Based on the results of comparing other fields, I know for sure that there is no error in the business logic. But I don’t understand why this difference in milliseconds occurs precisely with a remote build and how can I ignore this difference in nanoseconds.

My code line for comparison dates:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(expected.instant, actual.createdAt)
```

Comment: Are you testing an actual requirement?  Does the stakeholder actually require this behavior in precisely this way? Your requirement may not be realistic if processing times or data transit times are a factor.

Comment: Looks like a difference of precision (micros vs nanos), not a difference of nanoseconds. Any chance the actual values are being passed through a database or otherwise that could truncate the timestamp differently (dependent on platform) before they are compared?

Comment: Instead of getting times using `Instant.now()` (or whatever), create a component which provides timestamps. Then you can mock this component in your unit tests to get deterministic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the value is *near* rather than *equals*:

```
Assertions.assertTrue(Math.abs(expected.instant.until(actual.createdAt, MICROS)) < 10)
```

Adjust the units (NANOS for finer granularity, MILLIS for coarser granularity) and the amount that counts as "near".

A threshold of 10 MICROS would have passed the test with the values you posted, but I would relax the requirement as much as you can to avoid false negatives.

Comment: Even better: test for less than a certain interval.